# Bootstrap 4 JS Tab Not Redirecting

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following markup:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="tab-content">
  <form class="tab-pane active" id="login">
      <fieldset>
          <legend>Sign In</legend>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username">Username</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="username" type="text" required="required" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" required="required" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SIGN IN</button>
          </div>
      </fieldset>
      <a class="d-block text-center" href="#password-reset" data-toggle="tab">Forgot Password?</a>
  </form>

  <form class="tab-pane" id="password-reset">
      <fieldset>
          <legend>Forgot Password</legend>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" required="required" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SEND RESET</button>
          </div>
      </fieldset>
      <a class="d-block text-center" href="#login" data-toggle="tab">Go Back</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

The idea is that one or the other form will be displayed.

What is currently happening is that whenever I click on my Forgot Password anchor it goes to the form with the `password-reset` ID. Then whenever I click on my Go Back anchor it does go back to the form with the `login` ID.

Where I'm running into an issue is if I attempt to go back to the form with the `password-reset` ID. Currently it does nothing if I click on the anchor.

Comment: `href="#login"` and `href="#password-reset"` are the div id in the same html document?

Comment: Got it, It do not works for a second time clicked I guess it's a problem with event delegation read https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @OtávioBarreto so then this is a bug within the Bootstrap 4 framework?

Comment: I guess it's on jquery code inside bootstrap it  looks like  they forgot to event delegation.